# what is webclient & uses of webclient in .net

Tags: .net, webclient

What is webclient & uses of webclient?

Comment: This reads like an exam or interview question.

Comment: Change the Tag to C# , the Question is not asp.net mcv related unless you be more specific

Comment: The answer to this question is really really easy to find by googling. The first hit when googling `webclient c#` states: `Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.`

Answer (score 4):

[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is a class that allows you to send HTTP requests to a remote address from a .NET application. Here's an example in a console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.